# How do i rotate an animation i imported as an FBX

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I have 2 animations I have imported. Both as a .fbx. 
One is a character turning and running and the other is the character just running.

I am having a problem syncing up the rotation.

My question is - is it possible for me to rotate the full running rotation so that it can line up with the turning animation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new action that rotates your character in right angle. Make sure that you have only rotation keys:

[image]

2. Next, open NLA editor. Place rotation strip over your animation (in my case I called it "jumping"):

[image]

To add strip press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Make sure that animation data are empty.

3. In strip settings (<kbd>N</kbd>-panel) set blending to "Add".

[image]